# C++ Programa para invertir una palabra

Tags: c++

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void invertidor (char cadena[], int tamano)
{
    int tamano2=tamano;
    char invertido[tamano2];

    for (int x=0, y=tamano; x<tamano && y>=0; x++, y--)
    {
        invertido[x]=cadena[y];
    }
    cout<<"> "<<cadena<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"> "<<invertido<<endl<<endl;
    return;
}

int main ()
{

    char opcion;
    string palabra;
    int longitud, longitud2;

    while (opcion!='n')
    {
        system ("cls");
        cout<<"> Ejercicio 6"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"> Ingrese una palabra: ";
        cin>>palabra;
        longitud=palabra.length();

        char cadena[palabra.size()+1];
        strcpy(cadena, palabra.c_str());

        longitud2=strlen(cadena);

        invertidor (cadena,longitud2);

        cout<<"> Desea hacer una nueva operacion? (s/n): ";
        cin>>opcion;

        if (opcion=='n')
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que no aparece la palabra invertida al final.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código no funciona por no tener en cuenta el caracter de `c` de fin de cadena `'\0'`. Al ser el primer caracter que inviertes... pues siempre aparecerá una cadena  de longitud 0 (aunque después esté el resto) ;-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void invertidor (char cadena[], int tamano)
{
    char invertido[tamano];

    for (int x=0, y=tamano-1; x<tamano; x++, y--)
    {
        invertido[x]=cadena[y];
    }
    invertido[tamano] = '\0';
    cout<<"> "<<cadena<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"> "<<invertido<<endl<<endl;
    return;
}

int main ()
{

    char opcion;
    string palabra;
    int longitud, longitud2;

    while (opcion!='n')
    {
        system ("cls");
        cout<<"> Ejercicio 6"<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"> Ingrese una palabra: ";
        cin>>palabra;

        char cadena[palabra.size()+1];
        strcpy(cadena, palabra.c_str());

        longitud=strlen(cadena);

        invertidor (cadena,longitud);

        cout<<"> Desea hacer una nueva operacion? (s/n): ";
        cin>>opcion;

        if (opcion=='n')
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu codigo resuelve directamente mi pregunta

Comment: Para eso estamos. Me ha pasado tantas veces XDDD que lo vi a la primera. Por cierto en c++ siempre que puedas usa strings como te comenta @Dev.Joel es mucho mejor ;-)

Comment: Lo se, de hecho salio mucho mejor con strings (no crei que se pudiera) pero me lo solicitan con cadenas y por eso, igual gracias a Dev y a ti :)

Comment: @Malthael cadenas y strings son el mismo concepto. Creo que en realidad te refieres a que te pidieron el ejercicio con arreglos de caracteres (`char []`).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster asi es amigo, me pidieron hacer el programa con arreglos

Answer (score 3):

Por qué usar un arreglo y no directamente un String

```
string cadena = "Hola mundo!";
string aux_cadena = "";

for (int i = cadena.size(); i >=0 ; i--)
     aux_cadena += cadena[i];

cout<<"El texto normal es: "<<cadena<<endl;
cout<<"El texto invertido es: "<<aux_cadena<<endl;
return 0;
```

Comment: Pues.. la verdad no pense que se pudiera invertir una string, a ver dejame probar

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Aunque ya está resuelta la respuesta, la solución más sencilla es usar iteradores:

```
int main()
{
  std::string palabra;
  std::cout << "Introduce una palabra\n";
  std::cin >> palabra;

  std::string invertida(palabra.rbegin(),palabra.rend());
  std::cout << "Palabra invertida: " << invertida << '\n';
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: El usuario original usa arreglos de `char`, así que podría ser también una solución usar [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: Yo creo que cuando aprendes se usan arreglos por defecto hasta que conoces los puntos fuertes de los iteradores... de hecho la STL funciona enteramente a base de iteradores. `std::reverse` es otra alternativa perfectamente válida. Si no hay que reescribir el algoritmo a mano mejor que mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código no funciona porque pega la vuelta, realiza esto

```
Ingresada  abandonado 
0 obandonada A<>O
1 odandonaba B<>D
2 odandonaba A<>A
3 odandonaba N<>N
4 odanodnaba D<>O
5 odanodnaba D<>O
6 odandonaba N<>N
7 odandonaba A<>A
8 odandonaba B<>D
9 abandonada A<>O
```

Proba con este codigo

```
char* Invertidor (string palabraOriginal)
{
    int tamano = strlen(palabraOriginal);
    char palabraInvertida[tamano];
    int posOri = tamano;
    for (int posInv=0; posInv<tamano ; posInv++)
    {        
        palabraInvertida[posInv]=palabraOriginal[posOri];
        posOri--;
    }
    return palabraInvertida;
}
```

Comment: Pues en la funcion que habia creado cree dos arreglos de caracteres, uno que capte la frase ingresada en la funcion main y la otra que almacene la frase a invertir, probare tu codigo a ver que tal

Comment: La frase ingresada seria palabraOriginal, y la que almacena invertir seria palabraInvertida

Comment: Ya lo probe y sale esto: [Error] request for member 'lenght' in 'palabraOriginal', which is of non-class type 'char*'

Comment: @Malthael Ahí agregue información acerca de porque no funciona tu codigo

Comment: Prueba con 
    `tamano = strlen(palabraOriginal)` es para obtener el length de tu cadena de caracteres

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti gracias, no sabia donde estaba el error, ya me ayudaron a arreglar el problema, pero igual no sabia donde era que fallaba

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti Perdón por la publicidad: [usa el pre-incremento/decremento](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) siempre que sea posible :)

Comment: En esta respuesta hay un error, se está devolviendo un puntero a un dato que está en el stack, **palabraInvertida**, y que será sobrescrito por cualquier operación de llamada que se haga posterior a esta.

Answer (score 1):

Conviene usar las funciones específicas de la biblioteca estándar, reverse() y reverse_copy(). Por ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::string cadena = "Hola mundo!";
    std::reverse(cadena.begin(), cadena.end());
    std::cout << "anedca: " << cadena << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hay tantas soluciones.. muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estudiare esas funciones

Comment: @Malthael Por regla general, conviene usar los algoritmos de la biblioteca estándar antes que el código artesanal, y en este caso existen funciones específicas para invertir un rango de elementos.

Comment: `anedca` no es `cadena` al reves ;)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es un híbrido entre anedac y nadeca

Comment: @asdasdasd ¡Un híbrido! No juguemos a ser dioses... ;P

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma puedes hacerlo interactivo de una manera corta.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string str, new_str;
    cout<<"introduzca una cadena: ";
    getline(cin, str);
   
    for(int i = str.length(); i>=0;i--){
        new_str += str[i];
    }
    cout<<new_str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _¿Qué hace este código?_ Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Dado que es un ejercicio para un estudiante, es conveniente que tenga más de una forma de hacerlo. Esta es otra, utilizando otras construcciones simples. Puse una cadena preinicializada para que fuera más sencillo para experimentar. La cadena devuelta por la función se debe liberar al final cuando no se necesita más.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char* invert(string& oriStr)
{
    int strLen = oriStr.length();
    char* invStr = new char[strLen];
    
    if (invStr)
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < strLen; idx++)
            invStr[idx] = oriStr[strLen - 1 - idx];
    }
    
    return invStr;
}

int main()
{
    string oriStr = "Anita lava la Tina";
    
    cout << "Texto original:  " << oriStr << endl; 

    char* invStr = invert(oriStr);
    
    cout << "Texto invertido: " << invStr << endl; 
    
    delete invStr;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Esta es otra alternativa. En este caso la inversión se hace in-situ, sin crear otra cadena. El índice se hace mover desde ambos extremos de la cadena hacia el centro. Hay una pequeña optimización en la función `invert()` para el caso de cadenas con un número impar de caracteres.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void invert(char* oriStr)
{
    int strLen = strlen(oriStr);
    
    for (int idx = 0; idx < strLen / 2; idx++)
        swap( oriStr[idx], oriStr[strLen - 1 - idx]);
}

int main()
{
    char oriStr[20];
    sprintf(oriStr, "Anita lava la Tina");
    
    cout << "Texto original:  " << oriStr << endl; 

    invert(oriStr);
    
    cout << "Texto invertido: " << oriStr << endl; 
    
    return 0;
}
```